# lmer - "Invalid grouping factor specification"

Tags: r, grouping, lme4, mixed-models

I imported -in R Studio -the data set happiness.csv from https://www.kaggle.com/anamvillalpando/world-happiness-ranking.

Save the the data set as a dataframe (with 158  rows and 7 variables) and group the variables using the variable Region.

```
    datagD <- groupedData(Happiness.Score~df|Region, data= data.df) #group the data
```

I get an error attempting to run a linear mixed modell with intercept:
independent var: Happiness.Score
covariables: Economy..GDP.per.Capita., Family , (Health..Life.Expectancy.)^2 , Freedom

Code:

```
lmer(formula = Happiness.Score ~ Economy..GDP.per.Capita. + Family + Health..Life.Expectancy.)^2 + Freedom + (1|Economy..GDP.per.Capita. + Family + (Health..Life.Expectancy.)^2 + Freedom), data=datagD)
```

Error:

> �+� not meaningful for factors�^� not meaningful for factors�+� not meaningful for factors: Invalid grouping factor specification, Economy..GDP.per.Capita. + Family + (Health..Life.Expectancy.)^2 +     Freedom

I get this error message, after running following code (as a suggestion in other post)

```
remotes::install_github("lme4/lme4")
```

Could you give me an idea, please, what could be the problem there?

Thank you very much in advance for your help! :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with `(Health..Life.Expectancy.)^2`? It seems like your `Health..Life.Expectancy.` column is not numeric. Is that what you expect?

Comment: it should be: datagD$Health..Life.Expectancy
datagD$Health..Life.Expectancy is nummeric.

Comment: Thank you!
I already find the error: Just use the original data, without group them.